# How do I edit a comment inside the postSchema(postSchema)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, edit

I am working on an app where user can post and comment on an already posted post.
So my goal is to make it so that if a user posts a comment and they can edit it as they see fit, that's how I'm trying to edit a comment that's inside a post. and it doesn't work for me, please help! I work with MERN (mongoose, express, react, nodejs). I can add a comment successfully, but I don't know how to edit this comment.

here is the publication schema (PublicationSchema )

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PublicationSchema = new Schema({
    posterID: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    posterNom: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    posterAvatar: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    message: {
        type: String,
        trim: true, 
    },
    picture: String,
    video: String,
    likers: {
        type: [
            {
                likerID: String,
                likerNom: String,
                likerAvatar: String,
                likerTime: Number
            }
        ],
        required: true
    },
    commentaires: {
        type: [
            {
                commentID: String,
                commentNom: String,
                commentAvatar: String,
                commentText: String,
                commentPicture: String,
                commentTime: Number,
                reponse: {
                    type: [
                        {
                            type: String,
                            reponseID: String,
                            reponseNom: String,
                            reponseAvatar: String,
                            reponseText: String,
                            reponsePicture: String,
                            responseTime: Number
                        }
                    ]
                },
            }
        ],
        required: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const PublicationModel = mongoose.model('publications', PublicationSchema);
module.exports = PublicationModel;
```

et voici ce que j'ai essayé de faire mais malheureusement ça ne marche

if(!ObjectID.isValid(request.params.id)) return response.status(400).send('l'identifiant inconnu');

```
try {
    await PublicationModel.findById(request.params.id).then((data) =>{
        const commentaire = data.commentaires.find((comment)=>
            comment._id.equals(request.body.commentID)
        )
        
        if(commentaire){
            commentaire.commentText = request.body.text;

            data.save((err)=>{
                if(!err) return response.status(200).json(data);

                else return response.status(500).send(err);
            })
        }else{
            response.send('erreur');
        }
    });
   
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```